# SUM values from a table and subtract it to a SUM of values from another table having the same IDs

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, inventory_tbl and withdrawal_tbl, both have product_id, quantity and amount. I would like to sum all the quantity of the inventory_tbl and subtract it to the sum of all the quantity in the withdrawal_tbl that have the same product_id for both tables. Meaning;

inventory_tbl

```
product_id | quantity  | amount
1          | 10        | 10000
2          | 20        | 20000
3          | 30        | 30000
```

withdrawal_tbl

```
product_id | quantity  | amount
1          | 5         | 5000
2          | 10        | 10000
3          | 20        | 20000
```

Remaining_tbl

```
product_id | quantity  | amount
1          | 5         | 5000
2          | 10        | 10000
3          | 10        | 10000
```

I have this SQL Statement so far but it's giving me the wrong information

```
"SELECT inventory_tbl.product_id As 'Product ID', SUM(inventory_tbl.quantity) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.quantity), SUM(inventory_tbl.total) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.total) 
FROM withdrawal_tbl, inventory_tbl GROUP BY inventory_tbl.product_id"
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the expected result and what wrong information did you get?

Comment: you are doing cross product instead use inner join

Comment: inventory_tbl.total how you get this value?

Comment: Do you want your `remaining_tbl` to be the desired result of your query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing Cross Product instead of Inner join that is the problem.

Change your query to something like this

```
"SELECT inventory_tbl.product_id As 'Product ID', SUM(inventory_tbl.quantity) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.quantity), SUM(inventory_tbl.total) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.total) 
FROM withdrawal_tbl inner join inventory_tbl on inventory_tbl.product_id = withdrawal_tbl.product_id  GROUP BY inventory_tbl.product_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

use Inner join for the desired output ,try this :

```
"SELECT inventory_tbl.product_id As 'Product ID', SUM(inventory_tbl.quantity) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.quantity), SUM(inventory_tbl.total) - SUM(withdrawal_tbl.total) 
FROM inventory_tbl INNER JOIN withdrawal_tbl on inventory_tbl.product_id =withdrawal_tbl.product_id group by inventory_tbl.product_id;"
```